# Caesar Shift Encryption Objective C

Tags: objective-c, encryption, nsstring, char

I'm learning Objective C and iOS development. I'm trying to recreate some of the projects we did in my Java class (I know they're completely different) but I'm running into trouble in one of the projects. We were doing a caesar shift in a lab one day. A string manipulation lab. It was a really basic deal in Java... a for loop through the string and change each character. I can't seem to find any way to change individual characters in Objective C. I've looked through the NSMutableString documentation and NSString documentation and I know I can do a

`[NSString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:(NSRange *) withString:(NSString *)`

but that doesn't really help because I don't know what I'm going to be replacing with. I need to find a way to grab a character at a specific index and change it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the `[NSString characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)]` method

E.g.

```
NSString *string = @"abcde";
NSString *character = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",[string characterAtIndex: 0]];
NSLog(@"%@", character);
```

Result: a

Using this, and an `NSMutableString`, you can build the string you need.

Ussing `appendString` you can add to the end of an `NSMutableString`

Comment: `-characterAtIndex:` returns a `unichar`, not a `NSString`. -1 until fixed.

Comment: I swear I looked and didn't see anything about characterAtIndex! That's exaclty what I would use for Java `string.chatAt();` that's frustrating. Thank you for the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to do this would be using a good old C-string, as that allows you to change the bytes without the overhead of reallocating a different string every time:

```
NSString *ceasarShift(NSString *input)
{
    char *UTF8Str = strdup([input UTF8String]);

    int length = [input length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
         UTF8Str[i] = changeValueOf(UTF8Str[i]); // some code here to change the value
    }

    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:UTF8Str];
    free(UTF8Str);

    return result;
}
```

This reduces overhead, and although you have to free the data you allocated when you are done, it gives you the advantage of not relying on a high level API, improving performance drastically. (The difference between an array set and a dynamic method lookup is ~5 CPU cycles, which means a lot if you are doing any major sort of encryption)

Maybe also look into `NSMutableData` for this kind of task, instead of `NSString`, as the random `\0` may per chance appear in the result string.

Comment: This is asking for trouble if the input contains anything that requires more than one byte to represent in UTF8 -- parsing a UTF8 string byte-by-byte as an ordinary C string can only end in tears.

Comment: I appreciate the answer and I'm sure you have it right... but the only thing I know about regular C is the fact that you can define a function. I started with Objective-C just this week. Maybe one of these days this answer will be better for me but for now it's a bit dangerous ;)